# Using a loop to create a list

Tags: excel, vba, loops, reference

I'm trying to create a loop using VBA in Excel to make my code less chunky. Currently what I have is:

```
path1 = Sheets("A").Range("Directory").Value & "\" & Sheets("Selection").Range("N10").Value & ".jpg"
path2 = Sheets("A").Range("Directory").Value & "\" & Sheets("Selection").Range("N11").Value & ".jpg"
```

This goes on up to ppath15 and cell N24. The code simply creates a list of directory address for some pictures which I'll then insert into PowerPoint or Word. I already have the working code for that but it's not looped as well. What I"m trying to find is a way to reference the name (e.g. path(i)?) and cell (e.g. N(j)?) using a loop.

Note: "Directory" above is a named cell that contains a folder address e.g. "C:"
The lookup range (N10 to N24) contains the jpg names.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a possible solution

```
Dim paths() As Variant
Dim i As Long

paths = Application.Transpose(Sheets("Selection").Range("N10:N24").Value)
For i = LBound(paths) to UBound(paths)
    paths(i) =  Sheets("A").Range("Directory").Value & "\" & paths(i)  & ".jpg"
Next i
```

Another possibility:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim cell As Range

With Sheets("Selection").Range("N10:N24")
    ReDim paths(1 to .Rows.Count) As String
    For i = 1 to .Rows.Count
        paths(i) =  Sheets("A").Range("Directory").Value & "\" & cell & ".jpg"
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: Thanks user3598756 for the very fast reply. I tried the first solution and it works! Makes my code much shorter now.